# How to properly use nth-child in jQuery to step through objects of a type?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've run into a bit of an odd bug which seems specific to the `nth-child` selection syntax in `jQuery`.  I can use `$('list').each()` successfully to step through only the lists in the HTML below, however when using the `nth-child` selection clause it seems to count the `<br />` tag between the two `list` blocks.

For the HTML:

```
<list id="c" view="vw_project_content" where="`project` = %%2%%">
    <item>
        <b>$$title$$</b><br />
        $$message$$
        <br />
    </item>
</list>
<br />
Discussion:
<list id="p" view="vw_project_posts" where="`project` = %%2%%" limit="100">
    <item>
        <b>$$poster_id$$</b><br />
        $$message$$
        <br />
    </item>
</list>
```

And the following code:

```
console.log($('list:nth-child(1)'));
console.log($('list:nth-child(2)'));
console.log($('list:nth-child(3)'));
```

I receive the output:

```
[list#c, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
[prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
[list#p, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
```

However, if I remove the `<br />` between the two `list` blocks it produces:

```
[list#c, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
[list#p, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
[prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
```

Is there a proper way to select the `nth-child` of a specific type reliably, without needing to know what exists between the targeted blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing those results is beause of the way the nth-child() selector works. In your example code when you are trying to use `$('list:nth-child(2)')` what you are telling it to grab is a `list` element that is the second child of it's parent element. Within your HTML `list#c` is the first child of it's parent and `list#p` is the third child of it's parent. That is why you receive an empty response for `$('list:nth-child(2)')` when the `<br />` tag is present.

If what you are trying to do is get a specific position within a group of `list` elements you could try using the `eq()` selector instead. For example:

Note: The eq() selector is 0-indexed instead of 1-indexed.

```
console.log($('list:eq(0)'));
console.log($('list:eq(1)'));
```